# SELECT строку из таблицы MySQL, где присутствуют все, без исключений, значения из WHERE

Tags: mysql

Доброго времени суток!

Есть 3ри таблицы: **t**, **t_s**, **s**
В таблицах **t** и **s** по две колонки ***id*** и ***val***
**t_s**, это соединяющая таблица с колонками ***id***, ***t_id*** и ***s_id***
В общем, структура взаимодействия, как не сложно догадаться, что-то типа этого:
**t**.***val*** <-> **t**.***id*** -> **t_s**.***t_id*** <-> **t_s**.***s_id*** <- **s**.***id*** <->  **s**.***val***

Задача:
**t**.***id*** пересекаются с **s**.***id*** в таблице **t_s**. Мне нужно получить все **t**.***val*** которые пересекается с **s**.***val*** со значениями [*SVal1* и *SVal3*], не какое-либо из введённых значений, а именно все ведённые значения (и *SVal1*, и *SVal3*).

Инструкция которая у меня получилась, выводит строки **t**.***val*** которые пересекается с любой из искомых **s**.***val***:

```
SELECT val FROM t WHERE id IN (SELECT t_s.t_id FROM t_s
            LEFT JOIN s ON s.id = t_s.s_id
            WHERE s.val IN ('SVal1','SVal3'));
```

Визуальный пример:
Таблица **t:**

```
id:   Val:    
1     TVal1
2     TVal2
3     TVal3
4     TVal4
```

Таблица **s:**

```
id:   Val:    
1     SVal1
2     SVal2
3     SVal3
4     SVal4
```

Таблица **t_s:**

```
id:   t_id:   s_id:
1      2       1
2      1       3
3      3       4
4      4       1
5      1       1
```

Должен вернуть: *TVal1*
А не: *TVal1*, *TVal2*, *TVal4*

Надеюсь не слишком запутано )
Заранее спасибо за уделённое мне внимание.
**P.S**: Возможно, это не самая удачная схема взаимодействия 2х таблиц (**t** и **s**), где каждая из строк таблицы **t**, может пересекаться с любым количеством строк таблицы **s** – и наоборот. Буду рад любой альтернативе )

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.val
  FROM t
  JOIN t_s ON t.id = t_s.t_id
  JOIN s ON s.id = t_s.s_id 
 WHERE s.val IN ('SVal1','SVal3')
 GROUP BY t.id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Comment: Думаю, на случай появления дублей записей в t_s лучше сделать условие `HAVING` таким: `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.id) = 2`